# How would I measure/record the total training time for an artificial neural network algorithm for keras / tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I would like to record the total time to train an ANN algorithm, but I can't figure out how.I get the usual training dialogue for each step e.g.:
  `7/7 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2611 - accuracy: 0.9816`

Is there a utility that could do this for me? It's because I would like to investigate whether more complicated algorithms are worthwhile considering potentially longer training times.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is to create a custom callback. Code below will print out the training duration  when training is completed.

```
class TRA(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TRA, self).__init__()
    
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.start_time= time.time()
        
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        stop_time=time.time()
        tr_duration= stop_time- self.start_time            
        hours = tr_duration // 3600
        minutes = (tr_duration - (hours * 3600)) // 60
        seconds = tr_duration - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))
        msg = f'training elapsed time was {str(hours)} hours, {minutes:4.1f} minutes, {seconds:4.2f} seconds)'
        print(msg)
```

then use this code

```
callbacks=[TRA()]
history=model.fit(...   callbacks=callbacks ....)
```

in model.fit   include parameter callbacks as shown above